# Show hide of HTML table is not working in JavaScript (IE8)

Tags: javascript, html, css

`OnClick` of `Checkbox` I want to `Show`/ `Hide` the HTML table. I tried like below

**HTML**

```
 <tr id="trfeedback" runat="server" visible="false">
            <td style="width: 5%">
            </td>
            <td style="width: 90%">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkFeedback" runat="server" Text="Send Feedback" Width="6%" onclick="toggleTable();" />
            </td>
            <td style="width: 5%">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <table id="trchkOptions" runat="server">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 5%">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkOption1" runat="server" Width="5%" />
                    Option 1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;To&nbsp;
                    RA 1,&nbsp; RA 2
                </td>
                <td style="width: 5%">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 5%">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkOption2" runat="server" Width="5%" />
                    Option 2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;To&nbsp;
                    HMS, VMS.
                </td>
                <td style="width: 5%">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 5%">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkOption3" runat="server" Width="5%" />
                    Option 3&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;To,
                    RA 1,&nbsp; RA 2.
                </td>
                <td style="width: 5%">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

**JS**

```
 function toggleTable() {
        var lTable = document.getElementById("chkFeedback");
        lTable.style.display = (lTable.style.display == "table") ? "none" : "table";
    }
```

but it is not working. I don't know where I am going wrong. The HTML is [in this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h3y3zkuh/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a working version of your code which used checkboxes `checked` property to show hide the table.

Here are some minor changes that I made:

```
<!-- setting the initial state to checked and passing this to toggle function-->
<input id="chkFeedback" type="checkbox" name="chkFeedback" onclick="toggleTable(this);" />
```

And, then the javascript function

```js
function toggleTable(cb) {
    var lTable = document.getElementById("trchkOptions");  
    lTable.style.display = cb.checked ? "table": "none";
}
```

```html
<tr id="trfeedback">
 <td style="width: 5%">
                </td>
 <td style="width: 90%">
                    <span style="display:inline-block;width:6%;"><input id="chkFeedback" type="checkbox" name="chkFeedback" onclick="toggleTable(this);" /><label for="chkFeedback">Send Feedback</label></span>
                </td>
 <td style="width: 5%">
                </td>
</tr>
 
            <table id="trchkOptions" style='display:none'>
 <tr>
  <td style="width: 5%">
                    </td>
  <td>
                        <span style="display:inline-block;width:5%;"><input id="chkOption1" type="checkbox" name="chkOption1" /></span>
                        Option 1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;To&nbsp;
                        RA 1,&nbsp; RA 2
                    </td>
  <td style="width: 5%">
                    </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="width: 5%">
                    </td>
  <td>
                        <span style="display:inline-block;width:5%;"><input id="chkOption2" type="checkbox" name="chkOption2" /></span>
                        Option 2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;To&nbsp;
                        HMS, VMS.
                    </td>
  <td style="width: 5%">
                    </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="width: 5%">
                    </td>
  <td>
                        <span style="display:inline-block;width:5%;"><input id="chkOption3" type="checkbox" name="chkOption3" /></span>
                        Option 3&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;To,
                        RA 1,&nbsp; RA 2.
                    </td>
  <td style="width: 5%">
                    </td>
 </tr>
</table>
 
        </table>
```

Comment: what is `checked` in checkbox?

Comment: It is an [attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp) of the checkbox determining whether you have selected (checked) it or not.

Comment: by default i want it **not to be checked**..Shd I remove that ?

Comment: If by default it is not checked do you want your table to be visible?

Comment: no, on page load table shd also be not visible. once i checked the table shd get visible

Comment: hi @aks, are you their? need one validation help regarding this. let me know if u can help

Comment: @code: I would be very happy to help although I think you need to post a new question if you have one.

Comment: aah, sure.will post the new question though its a simple one but I hate when people downvote it.

Comment: hi aks, can u help me with the validation.please. As I tried but it is not working. the above link is my question.

Answer (score 1):

Updated the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h3y3zkuh/1/).
Basically you must call `window.getComputedValue` to get the  computed css value.

`Element.style.display` works only when the display is defined in the style attribute in the code.

IE8 workaround:

```
((window.getComputedStyle ? window.getComputedStyle(lTable) : lTable.currentStyle).display === "table") ? "none" : "table";
```

However I can't test it, as I don't have IE8.

Comment: its not working in `IE 8`.Sorry I forgot to mention that

Comment: still not working :( Even it is not working in `CHROME` also

Comment: In console it is showing as `frmEmployee_Exit_Interview.aspx:187 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
frmEmployee_Exit_Interview.aspx:276 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
frmEmployee_Exit_Interview.aspx?userid=996:1006 Uncaught ReferenceError: disablegrid is not defined
http://localhost:62999/ERP%20Lite/Images/FNDSSCORP.gif Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Make sure you the code is loaded onDomReady or onLoad. In fiddle click on "javascript" and choose the correct option in "load type".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110708/discussion-between-jakub-rozek-and-coder).